# cant check out from github

Tags: android-studio, github

I created a project in AndroidStudio and I am tring to check out from github.
I select git and clone project from github. It is successed but when I open the project it is empty and sais "Error Loading Project: Cannot load 2 modules Details"

Comment: "I open the project it is empty"> If you mean the project on android-studio, what is the content of your project repository?